# Sharing of array list or variable between 2 distributed tensorflow processes

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, data-sharing

I am presently working on Distributed tensorflow considering 2 worker processes and facing the issue of sharing variable between these two worker process. 
I found tf.get_collection/tf.add_collection but still unable to get the variable value shared between the 2 processes.

Adding Few details around how I want to share the data among the worker processes in Distributed Tensorflow :

```
def create_variable(layer_shape):
        with tf.variable_scope("share_lay"):
                layers = tf.get_variable("layers", shape=layer_shape, trainable=True)
        with tf.variable_scope("share_lay", reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
                layers = tf.get_variable("layers", shape=layer_shape, trainable=True)
        return layers

def set_layer(layers):
        tf.add_to_collection("layers", layers)

def get_layer(name):
        return tf.get_collection(name)[0]


taskid == 0:
  layers = create_variable(layer_shape)
  layers = <some value>
  set_layer(layers)
taskid == 1:
  layers = create_variable(layer_shape)
  layers = get_layer("layers")
```

I am getting an error when performing get_layer() as :

```
return tf.get_collection(name)[0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

It appears that the data cannot be share between the workers
Request some suggestions regarding the same
Any suggestions / pointers is appreciated,

Thanks,
Kapil

Comment: I have the same problem. Maybe we need to use MPI.

Comment: I am presently exploring the MPI for performing the send and recv between the processes using mpi4py, but got stuck into Pickle.dump issues, mpi4py uses pickle-based communication of generic Python object but when tried to send large buffers it is causing the error:Can't pickle local object

Answer (score 1):

I finally solve the same problem by using tf.train.replica_device_setter() to place the variables on parameter server and add them to a colletion. Later, I can use [tf.get_collection()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_collection) in any worker to return that collection, which is actually a python list. Note that tf.get_collection only return a **copy** of original collection. If you want to change the variables in the original collection, you should use [tf.get_collecion_ref](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_collection_ref) which actually returns the collection list itself.

Here is an example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('job_name', '',
                           """One of 'ps', 'worker' """)
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('task_index', 0,
                           """Index of task within the job""")

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec(
    {'ps': ['localhost:22222'],
    'worker': ['localhost:22223', 'localhost:22227']})
config = tf.ConfigProto(
            intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
            inter_op_parallelism_threads=1)
if FLAGS.job_name == 'ps':
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name='ps', task_index=FLAGS.task_index, config=config)
    server.join()
else:
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name='worker', task_index=FLAGS.task_index, config=config)
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(cluster=cluster)):
        #create a colletion 'shared_list' and add two variables to the collection 'shared_list'
        #note that these two variables are placed on parameter server
        a = tf.Variable(name='a', initial_value=tf.constant(1.0), 
                        collections=[tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, 'shared_list'])

        b = tf.Variable(name='b', initial_value=tf.constant(2.0), 
                        collections=[tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, 'shared_list'])

    #now let's print out the value of a+2.0 and b+2.0 using the collection 'shared_list' from different worker
    #note that tf.get_collection will return a copy of exiting collection which is actually a python list
    with tf.device('/job:worker/task:%d' %FLAGS.task_index):
        c = tf.get_collection('shared_list')[0] + 2.0    # a+2.0
        d = tf.get_collection('shared_list')[1] + 2.0    # b+2.0


    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                           is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index==0),
                                           config=config) as sess:
        print('this is worker %d' % FLAGS.task_index)
        print(c.eval(session=sess))
        print(d.eval(session=sess))
        server.join()
```

worker 0 will print out:

```
this is worker 0
3.0
4.0
```

worker 1 will print out:

```
this is worker 1
3.0
4.0
```

Edit: work 0 modifies the variable 'a' to 10, and then worker 1 prints out the new value of 'a', which becomes 10 immediately. Actually, variable 'a' is available for both worker 0 and worker 1 because they are in distributed setting. Below is an example. Also refers to this blog in [Amid Fish](http://amid.fish/distributed-tensorflow-a-gentle-introduction) by Matthew Rahtz for how to share variables in distributed tensorflow. Actually, we don't need any parameter server to share variables. Any two workers can share the same variable with each other as long as the two workers create two variables having exactly the same name.

Here is the example

```
import tensorflow as tf
from time import sleep

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string('job_name', '',
                           """One of 'ps', 'worker' """)
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer('task_index', 0,
                            """Index of task within the job""")

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec(
    {'ps': ['localhost:22222'],
     'worker': ['localhost:22223', 'localhost:22227']})

if FLAGS.job_name == 'ps':
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name='ps', task_index=FLAGS.task_index)
    server.join()
else:
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name='worker', task_index=FLAGS.task_index)
    with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(cluster=cluster)):
        # create a colletion 'shared_list' and add two variables to the collection 'shared_list'
        # note that these two variables are placed on parameter server
        a = tf.Variable(name='a', initial_value=tf.constant(1.0),
                        collections=[tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, 'shared_list'])

        b = tf.Variable(name='b', initial_value=tf.constant(2.0),
                        collections=[tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, 'shared_list'])

    # change the value of 'a' in worker 0
    if FLAGS.task_index == 0:
        change_a = a.assign(10)

    # print out the new value of a in worker 1 using get_collction. Note that we may need to
    # use read_value() method to force the op to read the current value of a
    if FLAGS.task_index == 1:
        with tf.device('/job:worker/task:1'):  # place read_a to worker 1
             read_a = tf.get_collection('shared_list')[0].read_value()  # a = 10

    with tf.train.MonitoredTrainingSession(master=server.target,
                                           is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0))as sess:
        if FLAGS.task_index == 0:
            sess.run(change_a)

        if FLAGS.task_index == 1:
            sleep(1)  # sleep a little bit to wait until change_a has been executed
            print(read_a.eval(session=sess))
        server.join()
```

worker 1 prints out

```
10
```

Comment: Thanks Luochao Wang for the response, I have few comments on above implementation :    1. If you walk through the replica setter code segment the complete code is executed by both the workers and they are performing the identical thing hence the expected out.                                                                 2. What I wanted is worker 0 modify the variable say "C" and the modified value of "C" becomes available to worker 1 when it access the tf.get_collection(key), something like what I have shown above in the previous question

Comment: As long as workers create variables with the same name and place the variables to the same device, then these variables are shared between these workers who create them. That means if worker 0 and worker 1 both create variables named 'a' and both place it to task 0. Then the variable 'a' is shared between worker 0 and worker 1. When worker 0 do something to 'a', worker 1 will know it  immediately.

Comment: Luochao Wang, Thanks for the response, I have one question, to get the better understanding, what is the sharing mechanism used by Tensorflow between the two processes, is it MMAP, MPI shared memory, CUDA Unified memory etc.